# Accessing items in dictionary of lists of dictionaries (Python) to create new dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists of dictionaries:

```
my_dict = {0: [{'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 2L, 'home_number': 4, 'road_id': 0},
     {'distance': 4.1, 'home_id': 1L, 'home_number': 2, 'road_id': 0}],
 1: [{'distance': 4, 'home_id': 3L, 'home_number': 5, 'road_id': 1}],
 2: [{'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 4L, 'home_number': 1, 'road_id': 2},
     {'distance': 6, 'home_id': 5L, 'home_number': 3, 'road_id': 2}]}
```

How can I get to:

```
final_dict = {1L : {1 : 2}, 2L : {1 : 4}, 3L : {1 : 5}, 4L : {1 : 1}, 5L : {1 : 3}}
```

1 is the index of a field that I would like to update (with the value of each inner dictionary). Each of these items have an ID which are the keys of final_dict.

What I've tried so far:

```
new_sort_attr = {}
for key,value in my_dict:
    for dictionary in value:
        new_sort_attr[dictionary['home_id']] = dictionary['home_number']
```

This gives me a TypeError.

Comment: `{x : 3}` is invalid, dictionary key must be a value (hashable), not variable/binding

Comment: 1R also is invalid and gives a syntax error.

Comment: I can't see any logical connection in how you want to 'restructure' the dict. Care to explain?

Comment: @user985366 I just gave some more info on how my_dict actually is.

Comment: So its basically a mapping of `home_id` to `home_number`? Did you try to write any code yourself?

Comment: @PaulRooney I suppose so. I just updated with what I originally tried, but I must have some confusion on how to access each individual inner dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
my_dict = {0: [{'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 2L, 'home_number': 4, 'road_id': 0},
     {'distance': 4.1, 'home_id': 1L, 'home_number': 2, 'road_id': 0}],
 1: [{'distance': 4, 'home_id': 3L, 'home_number': 5, 'road_id': 1}],
 2: [{'distance': 2.1, 'home_id': 4L, 'home_number': 1, 'road_id': 2},
     {'distance': 6, 'home_id': 5L, 'home_number': 3, 'road_id': 2}]}

final_dict = {1L : {1 : 2}, 2L : {1 : 4}, 3L : {1 : 5}, 4L : {1 : 1}, 5L : {1 : 3}}

# without dict comprehension
dout = {}
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    for d in v:
        dout[d['home_id']] = {1: d['home_number']}

# using dict comprehension
dout2 = {d['home_id']: {1: d['home_number']} for k, v in my_dict.iteritems() for d in v}

print final_dict
print dout
print dout2
```

Output

```
{1L: {1: 2}, 2L: {1: 4}, 3L: {1: 5}, 4L: {1: 1}, 5L: {1: 3}}
{1L: {1: 2}, 2L: {1: 4}, 3L: {1: 5}, 4L: {1: 1}, 5L: {1: 3}}
{1L: {1: 2}, 2L: {1: 4}, 3L: {1: 5}, 4L: {1: 1}, 5L: {1: 3}}
```

There are 2 methods, that are essentially equivalent, but some people like the one liners, whereas other feel that nested comprehensions make lines too long and code less readable.

What was missing from your code was that you iterated over the dict incorrectly (would have been an exception). You should use `iteritems` (python 2) or `items`(python 3) to yield the key, value pairs from the dict.

If you wanted to stick with iterating over the dict directly, you'd have to do something like

```
new_sort_attr = {}
for d in my_dict:
    for din in my_dict[d]:
        new_sort_attr[din['home_id']] = {1: din['home_number']}
```

secondly you never created the sub dict.  So instead of

```
new_sort_attr[dictionary['home_id']] = dictionary['home_number']
```

I did

```
dout[d['home_id']] = {1: d['home_number']}
```

Comment: In Python 3.x iteritems() is replaced by items()

Comment: Thanks for that. this is why I stated "You should use iteritems (python 2) or items(python 3) to yield the key, value pairs from the dict." in my answer. Besides if the OP is using the L qualifiers on his integers, he has to be using python 2

Answer (score 0):

The type error comes from bad syntax when iterating. 
When iterating over a dict, you get the keys. Instead of

`for key,value in my_dict:`

you should

`for key,value in my_dict.items():`

which gives you

`{1L: 2, 2L: 4, 3L: 5, 4L: 1, 5L: 3}`